# Run insert if no entry otherwise run update with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wpdb

Below function works with ajax ... but I am getting a null result ... I want that if there is no data in the database then insert operation is performed and when there is data the update should work. Only update or only insert works but when I use both ... the answer is null ... currently my zvotes table has no data so insert operation should be performed. In update it searches the same value and try to replace it with a new value. I want the user to enter once and then if he presses button again he can replace his previous value. Thanks I am getting null right now.. I am just pasting the php code .. with this there is a simple ajax call to show and parse passed json data to a div.

PHP Code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_star', 'star' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_star', 'star');


function star()
{
    //variables

    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    $user=$user_info->user_login;
    $passedvalue = $_POST['clickval'];
    $competition = $_POST['compete'];
    $aid = $_POST['foo'];
    global $wpdb;    
    //$sqll = "SELECT zvotes.zvotes FROM zvotes WHERE zvotes.votedby = '$user' && zvotes.zcompetition = '$competition'";

     $previous = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT zvotes.zvotes FROM zvotes WHERE zvotes.votedby = '$user' && zvotes.zcompetition = '$competition'");
    echo json_encode($previous);die();
    if (count($previous)>0){
    global $wpdb;    
    $reel = $wpdb->get_var("UPDATE zvotes SET zvotes.zvotes='$passedvalue' WHERE zvotes.votedby='$user' && zvotes.competition='$competition'");
    echo json_encode("hi i am blocking the insert operation");die();
    }

    else if(count($previous<1))
    {
        $wpdb->insert(
        'zvotes',
        array(
                'zvotes' => $passedvalue,
                'zcompetition' => $competition,
                'aid' => $aid,
                'votedby' => $user
            ));
     $sqll = "SELECT Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM zvotes WHERE zvotes.aid = '$aid' && zvotes.zcompetition = '$competition'";

     $reel = $wpdb->get_var($sqll) or die(mysql_error());
        echo json_encode ($reel);
        die();

}

}
```

Comment: please reply ... anybody

Comment: Why are you using array count on the `get_var` result? This part `count($previous<1))` will not work either. Also watch out for possible SQL injections.

Comment: You've got an early `die()` in there - I guess that's for debugging? Does the code still not work if you remove it?